# AWS Nginx Ingress creating Classic Load Balancer instead of Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to setup Application Load Balancer to forward traffic to Nginx Ingress controller in AWS.
To set up Nginx Ingress controller, I am using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.40.2/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy-tls-termination.yaml) YML which I got it from the [installation instructions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#tls-termination-in-aws-load-balancer-elb).

After deployment, everything is working fine and traffic is being forwarded to EKS pods correctly. However, the above YML file is creating '**Classic Load Balancer**' in aws where as I want to create '**Application Load Balancer**'. I changed '**service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: elb**' to '**service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: alb**' but still it is creating classic load balancer in AWS.

Please help in setting up the desired LB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just interested if you have tried to install nginx ingress via helm chart + specify `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: alb` annotation like [here](https://www.shogan.co.uk/how-tos/useful-nginx-ingress-controller-configurations-for-kubernetes-using-helm/) ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I haven't tried installing it with helm. I will try and update you.

Comment: I tried with the helm chart..it is still creating classic alb.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use ALB (Application Load Balancer) instead of NLB (Network Load Balancer), you need to use AWS ALB Ingress Controller with External DNS, not the NGINX Ingress Controller. See the details in [this official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html) and [this official AWS ALB Ingress Controller doc](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/)

I hope that answers your problems.

Comment: I setup ALB Ingress Controller initially, but since it does not support namespace based routing, I had to move away from it. The problem I am facing is when I am deploying ingress controller it is creating Classic LB instead of Application LB.

Comment: well afaik, all ingress controller execpt alb-ingress-controller is using classic nlb , not supported with alb

Comment: I assumed the same but I couldn't find anything related to this in documentation. Do you know if this is documented somewhere?

Comment: don't know thought... just based on my experience...

Comment: Hi @PrerakTiwari can you elaborate on what you mean my namespace based routing — for example, do you mean defining Ingress rules in namespace `foo` and routing to services in namespaces `bar`, `baz` and so on?

Answer (score -1):

It's OK when i use this method of installation :
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.40.2/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml

Comment: You mean its creating Application Load Balancer for you?

Comment: The creates a `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb`

Answer (score -3):

same issue for me with :

```
resource "helm_release" "ingress-nginx" {
  name       = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace  = "ingress-nginx"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  values = [
    file("values/ingress-nginx.values.yaml")
  ]
}
```

> 

```
controller:
  config:
    use-proxy-protocol: "true"
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  service:
    internal:
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: '*'
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```